# Distance between polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon

[image]I am working on my thesis project, whereby I am assessing the sediment volume changes of the Wadden Islands, The Netherlands, as they responded to sea level rise.

I have Polygon shape files of the relevant sediment I need. I need to calculate the distance travelled by the sediment (landwards) over several years (i.e. between 5500BC and 3850BC and so on until present day). See attached image - Purple is the sediment position in 3850BC and pink 5500BC.

Is there any way I can calculate the distance between these two polygons?

Comment: If you want the mean distance between all the features of the two polygons you can create Centroids for both and then use "Distance on nearest hub line to hub"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating centroids you can use the **NNJoin** plugin for QGIS. Do make sure your features layers are in the same projection before using this plugin. The name of the field which holds the distance can be specified.

It will join features from layer_A to the nearest features in layer_B and store the ID's and the distance in separate fields.

Comment: Since QGIS 3.8 you can also use the native processing tool "Join by nearest". Which does the same + some more options without the need of a plugin and saving the result as shp.

Answer (score 1):

first try to get center coordinates of polygons.Then use haversine formula to calculate the distance between center points of polygons